# Google Play Services Your app is not ready to be published

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I am just about to publish my game but hit a road block. I do not understand what I am asked to do, I can not find an answer or a solution for that matter. This is what it asks me to do:

```
FINAL CHECKS
None of your Android linked apps that support Android tablet are set as preferred for new players
None of your Android linked apps that support Android tv are set as preferred for new players
```

I have no clue how to set the preffered to players thing. Could someone help me out please??

Comment: Most likely something to do with your Screen compatibility range that you declared in the manifest. Read #7 in this launch checklist: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html. You should verify what have you declared in <supports-screens> tag.

Answer (score 4):

Check here https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting

> If you can't publish your game, check that exactly one of the client IDs has the This app is preferred for new installations option enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have already checked "Preferred for new android phone" or "Use for new installs" depending on which version of Google Play Console you use now on 2020 and you still get this error:

-Old version: None of your Android linked apps that support Android tablet are set as preferred for new players

-New version: An error occured publishing your game error code xxx

You simply delete your credential (linked app) on new version of Google Play Console and create it again. Then you will be able to publish.

I think there is a conflict/bug nowadays on Google Play Console